# How to give write and execute permissions to newly created files inside a WSL distro from Windows?

Tags: ubuntu, windows-subsystem-for-linux

The file permissions documentation for WSL in microsoft's page says:

> The default umask is applied when creating a new file inside of a WSL
> distribution from Windows. The default umask is 022, or in other words
> it allows all permissions except write permissions to groups and
> others.

I use `sudo chmod -R a+rwx /path/to/folder` on newly created directories. Since every article I've read about the aforementioned command say its a bad security practice, is there a better way to give write permissions to the default Windows user only for every newly created directories.